# I have some image data and I am training my SVM classifier on it and I see that the support vectors are all zero. what does it mean?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

Here is the code that I was using.

```
nfiles=40
i=0
y=[1]*20
y.extend([-1]*20)
traindata =np.zeros((40,1024));
for im in glob.glob("/home/name/Desktop/database/20trainset/*.png "):
    img = cv2.imread(im)
    img = im2double(img)
    img = rgb2gray(img)
    traindata[i] =img.reshape((1,1024))
    i+=1

clf = svm.SVC( kernel='rbf',C=0.05)
clf.fit(traindata,y)
print clf.support_vectors_
```

The i is to keep count of the number of files.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: C is far too small in clf = svm.SVC( kernel='rbf',C=0.05)

Comment: I have tested with c equal to 1, 0.5, 0.05, 0.005, 0.0005 and found that given my data set of 40, c=0.05 giving the best precision_score of all the c's.

Comment: Try C=100000, and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried c=1000000 and got a better f1_score than that of c=0.05 and for the rest of the c's, 0.05 was better. To be specific c=0.05 was giving an f1_score of 0.46891 while c=1000000 was giving 0.4961 and rest of c's are below 0.468.

Answer (score 2):

This means that using your parameters, optimal SVM is to do nothing (build a trivial model which simply answers one label).

```
cl(x) = sign( SUM_i alpha_i y_i K(x_i, x) + b ) = sign( b ) = const.
```

so yes, there is something wrong, as your **model does not use your training data at all**.

What are the reasons? In order to use RBF-SVM you need to fit two hyperparameters: `gamma` and `C`, in particular `C=0.05` is (probably) orders of magnitude too small to work well. Also - remember to normalize your data, because images are often represented as pixel intensitiy values (0-255) while SVM works better for a normally distributed values. Gamma also has to be carefully fitted (its default value in scikit-learn is 1/no. of features, thus it is really rough guess of a good value, rarely a good one).

As an example refer to [libsvm website](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and a plot showing relation of C and gamma values to the obtained accuracy on heart dataset

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I was not able follow what you are trying to say.

Comment: Which part is confusing? The short answer is "this is a sign of badly selected parameters of the method, you have to choose C and gamma of SVM to get correct results".